# Detecting if the RecyclerView is scrollable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am fetching messages in to the RecyclerView and I want to detect if the RecyclerView is scrollable

if it's scrollable I want to use `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);`

**I tried the following:**

`if(rv.getLayoutManager().canScrollVertically()){`

it returns true, even when the RecyclerView is **not** scrollable

`if(rv.canScrollVertically(-1) || rv_msg.canScrollVertically(1)){`

returns false, even when the RecyclerView **is** scrollable

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? If it's empty space at the top of the RV, you can setup your RV height to be wrap_content instead of match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

well `RecyclerView` view is always scrollable because it is in list style what can will work for you in that case you judge scrollability by your data size you are parsing

well it is not a perfect solution but can work for you.